# Data visualization with maps

Tags: java, graphics, maps, visualization

I'm building an app that will convert a conventional map to a data visualization where each district on the map is represented as a shape (circle, square?) and its size is dependent on the population of the district. Additionally, the shapes on the new map should have a somewhat accurate location relative to the other shapes.

How would you approach this?

EDIT: To be more specific, I have a spreadsheet with population counts for each district. In addition, I have a map (like google maps) that shows where each district is located geographically. I would like to output a visualization where each district is represented by a shape with its size dependent on the population. And, the shape's location on the visualization should convey where it lies relative to other districts geographically.

Comment: "Map" as in "Navigation Map"?

Comment: Yes, a Navigation map as in google maps. However, that may have been misleading. I will have a spreadsheet that has the information on each district's population and other characteristics.